# Prove that $1_{E_n}$ is pointwise convergent

Tags: characteristic-functions, sequence-of-function

Given that $E_n$ is an increasing sequence of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ .

What I did is that I took  $x\in E_m$ for some $m$, then as $E_n$ is increasing, $\forall n\geq m$ we have $x\in E_n$, then $1_{E_n}(x)=1$ , so $1_{E_n}\rightarrow 1$

But what if $x\notin E_n$ for all $n$ ?

Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then $1_{E_n}(x) = 0$ for all $n$ which also converge , $1_{E_n}(x) \to 0$.

So to conclude (with our comments) :

$$1_{E_n}(x) \to 1_{\cup_n E_n(x)}$$

Comment: So what is the limit 1 or 0 ?

Comment: it depends, if $x\in E_n$ for some $n$ ,than it is $1$ . otherwise , it is $0$

Comment: the sequence depends on $x$ , for each $x$ we get a sequence of numbers $(1_{E_n}(x) )_{n=1}^\infty$. and it converge to $1$ if $x\in E_n $ for some $n$ and to $0$ otherwise.

Comment: So it converges to a characteristic function ?

Comment: yes, $1_{\cup E_n}$.

Comment: Can we say that it converges to $1$ almost eveywhere ?

Comment: if $\cup E_n$  cover almost everything, yes. (what i mean is that it's complement has measure 0)

Comment: (but generally , no)